# Syntax coloring for VBS file in Visual Studio with a different extension

Tags: visual-studio-2010, syntax-highlighting

A program we work with in my office can be automated through VBScript Files, yet the files are saved with an extension *.RVB other then *.VBS. I'd like to use Visual Studio as my editor/debugger, which is working. Yet it is not coloring the code like it does if I have a *.VBS file open.

Under Tools->Options->File Extension I added "RVB" and set it's editor to Microsoft Visual Basic, yet it is still not applying any syntax highlighting to my file. What am I missing?

Comment: I just had to re-open the solution to solve this problem in VS2008, though I wasn't using the specific extensions you were.

Answer (score 0):

I realize this might be beyond what you had in mind. However, I see no acknowledgement to your solution so I am going out on a limb here. You could create a language extension and totally control all aspects of the coloring. This is easily transfered to 2010 (the example is in 2008) but remains relevant.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vstudio/bb851701

In this video, Hilton Giesenow illustrates a simple working Language Service. He begins by building a simple scanner colorizingsing based on regular expressions, then expands on this to implement the Managed Babel framework, integrating MPLex and MPPG directly into the Visual Studio build as well.